# $GOPATH directory and diskspace

Tags: go, diskspace

after a year or two developing with GO I had a look at my $GOPATH directory size and was surprised to see it was growing to a 4GB.

I understand that disk space is supposed (and it's not that much on this 128GB laptop SSD) to be cheap but still.

So my questions is, is there some good practice to manage the size $GOPATH directory ?

Would restarting from scratch would be a good idea? (although could be very much time consuming)

Comment: Your GOPATH contains not only the source of the packages, but also the object files, sometimes even for different architectures (if you crosscompiled) and/or with race detection enabled. As these are basically just cached version you can delete them (they are located in GOPATH/pkg).

Comment: As go get does a git clone for the dependencies you can also run a git gc --aggressive to free up some space

Comment: Also certain editors (e.g. Atom) create special executables next to source files when you debug apps or tests (e.g. `debug`), which you can delete freely.

Comment: Also you might have profile and test coverage output files in your `src` folder if you ever used those features. Also "temporary" executable binaries produced by `go build`. You can also remove these.

Comment: may you post what are the size of each folder **pkg**, **src** and **bin** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement, that deleting the `GOPATH` would be time consuming, sounds like you are managing the dependencies of your Go projects with plain `go get ...`. In my environment I do two things to make the `GOPATH` ephemeral.

1. Don't use plain `go get` for dependency management. Go 1.6 introduced the `/vendor` directory. Together with a dependency management tool like [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) every dependency for a certain project lies withing the project directory.

   1. This means, if don't need a dependency anymore you can wipe the `vendor` directory of the project and download the dependencies again. Therefore you only have dependencies on your disk, which you actually need.
   2. Also, if you stop working on a project and delete it from your disk, the dependencies also get deleted.
2. You can specify multiple paths in the `GOPATH`. Like the `PATH` environment variable you can split them by a colon. The interesting thing is, that Go uses the first path for downloading projects. On my machine the `GOPATH` looks like `$HOME/.gopath:$HOME/projects`. So if you put all your actual projects into the second directory, you will have an clear separation between your projects and dependencies. Thus you could wipe the first directory from time to time, but don't need to fear that you have to clone every of your projects, again.

These two things don't help to reduce the disk usage of your Go projects and their dependencies, but you get a better overview whats actually needed and makes you able to delete the dependency directory whenever you like.

Comment: Does option 2 work for Windows too? I believe if so, the separator will become `;` instead of `:`.